# Insert a character in a string based on character placement in another string

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two strings:

```
const originalSegments = '[ABC][XYZ][123][789]';

const format = 'X-XX-X';
```

I need to create a new string where the dashes are inserted between sets of characters in `originalSegments` based on the placement of separators in `format`.

Each set of a characters between brackets is equal to one `format` character,

i.e. `[*] === X`

The desired end result is:

```
'[ABC]-[XYZ][123]-[789]'
```

I can get the length of each section in `format`:

```
const formatSections = format.split('-');
const formatSectionLengths = formatSections.map(section => section.length);
// => [1, 2, 1]
```

And the number of segments in `originalSegments`:

```
const originalSegmentsCount = (regexToString.match(/\]\[/g) || []).length + 1;
// => 4
```

But I'm not sure what to do next.

Would `Array.prototype.reduce()` work for this? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose this solution for your case

```js
const originalSegments = "[ABC][XYZ][123][789]";
//convert all segments to ["ABC","XYZ","123","789"]
const segments = originalSegments.split('[').filter(x => x).map(x => x.split(']')[0]);
const format = 'X-XX-X'
let result = []
let segmentIndex = 0
//loop through format to find X for the replacement
for(let i = 0; i < format.length; i++) {
  const character = format[i]
  //if the current character is X, replace with segment data
  if(character === "X") {
     result.push(`[${segments[segmentIndex]}]`)
     //check the next segment
     segmentIndex++
     continue
  }
  result.push(character)
}

//convert all results to a string
const finalResult = result.join("")

console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```js
const text='[ABC][XYZ][123][789]',
  pat='X-XX-X';

let txt=text.replaceAll("][","],[").split(",");
console.log(pat.split("").reduce((a,c)=>
 a + (c==="X"?txt.pop():c)
, ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Another version using `regex` group matches and `map`

```js
const originalSegments = '[ABC][XYZ][123][789]';
const format = 'X-XX-X';

const segs = originalSegments.match(/(\[[\w]+\])/g);
const output = [...format]
  .map((ch) => (ch === "X" ? segs.shift() : ch))
  .join("");
  
console.log(output)
```